# tbl_regression sample size in model - gtsummary

Tags: gtsummary

Is there a way to add the sample size in the tbl_regression output.
Meaning the actual sample used for the model?

```
#example
tbl_regression(model, exponentiate = TRUE)
```

Thanks,

#gtsummary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to add the model N to a `tbl_regression()` table.

1. Use `modify_header()` to include the N in a column header. Requires gtsummary v1.3.6 or higher.
2. Use `add_n()` to add a column to the table with the number of observations. Requires the current dev version of gtsummary. Install the dev version with `remotes::install_github("ddsjoberg/gtsummary")`

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> '1.3.6.9013'

glm(response ~ age, trial, family = binomial) %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE) %>%
  modify_header(label ~ "**Characteristic, N = {N}**") %>% # Add N to the column header
  add_n() %>%                                              # Add N column to table
  add_nevent()                                             # Add Event N column to table
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel!, the first method worked, the second gives me the following error despite downloading and updating the entire package:     Error in UseMethod("add_n") : 
  no applicable method for 'add_n' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_regression', 'gtsummary')"   This is my input       `tbl_regression(model, exponentiate = TRUE)%>%
  modify_header(label ~ "**Characteristic, N = {N}**") %>% 
  add_n() %>%                                            
  add_nevent()`  Appreciate your help,

Comment: Did you install with remotes::install_github("ddsjoberg/gtsummary") ?

Comment: I was able to download it and get it to run.  I'm getting the following error once I use the code above:  `Error in eval(parse(text = text, keep.source = FALSE), envir) : 
  object 'N' not found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In tcm * w :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In tcm * y * w :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In y * w :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`

Comment: Post a reprex please